Does Oleyl Alcohol stain or discolor?
Will Oleyl Alcohol stain or discolor surfaces, just like short chains Ethanol or Isopropyl do?
There are many body or hair products containing Oleyl Alcohol (not volatile as ethanol is) which may rub up against clothing or furniture after application.
Thank you.

Lower alcohols don't "stain" anything, just dissolve things like paint. Oleyl alcohol might do it too, but is much less polar, quite like fat, from which it's derived.

Depends on the surface.

@Mithoron By dissolve things, do you mean dissolve dyes of fabric as well? There’s widely available information about short chain alcohols shifting dyes of certain fabrics, but there’s no warning regarding long chain alcohols. Are hair or body products unsafe then? Thank you.

@DrMoishePippik Do you think leave-in hair products are posing a risk to clothes then? Can it shift dyes of cotton, silk or leather? Is that just for Oleyl, or Cetyl or Cetearyl as well? Thank you.
